# Animate panning map in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, route, animation, pan

I want to create a short video illustrating the route of a proposed road by starting the map in one position, then panning to a number of other points. Is this possible in QGIS using the time manager or other methods?

I COULD export a high res image from QGIS and pan the image in Sony Vegas but I am wondering if it is possible using QGIS only.

Answer (score 1):

In QGIS you are able to do 3D maps (with **QGIS2threejs plugin**) and 2D animations (with **TimeManager plugin**) as described here: http://anitagraser.com/2011/11/20/nice-animations-with-time-managers-offset-feature/). But there is not a plugin for doing a 3D animation. However, there are some open source projects that would be interesting for that:

1. Blender, a 3D modeller which you can use importing your data from QGIS. You can find an example here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vX8BeuiXWeU
2. Horao, which is a visualisation tool for 3D GIS data: http://oslandia.github.io/horao/index.html
3. OpenWebGlobe, which allows you to create your own virtual globe applications running in the web browser. http://www.openwebglobe.org