# Animated maps in QGIS

Tags: qgis, animation

I would like to create an animated map/video in QGIS illustrating the route of a voyage (goig/panning from one stop to another). Something like http://www.animaps.com.

I don't think it is possible with Time Manager or MMQGIS? Maybe I'm wrong. With OpenLayers it should be feasible but it seems to require a lot of coding in Javascript and you still have to create the video afterwards from the screen animation.

Comment: QGIS really isn't an animation program. This exact question was asked a year ago, and still remains unanswered. https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/191911/animate-panning-map-in-qgis